# Why are there not 2 grid-cells horizontally adjacent to one another?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <span>1</span><span>2</span>
</div>
```

I'm expecting there to be 2 'grid-cells' horizontally adjacent from one another. Instead, they stack up vertically. Why is this?

I thought `grid-template-columns/rows` specified the dimensions & layout of grid-cells.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Respected Paulie_D. I feel people have lots of confusion regarding CSS-Grids.  And this problem may occur with future developers as well :) This is no typo or similar thing here I guess. Just a sincere opinion Sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How grid works is like this.You first set number of columns by `grid-template-columns`. In your case there was only one column and one row. I changed it to two columns and it worked as expected.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <span>1</span><span>2</span>
</div>
```

**QUICK TIP:** You can always use Developer Window `(CTRL+SHIFT+I)` in your Browser to check how many grid items I have.

Comment: I forgot `2fr` is not equivalent to `1fr 1fr` . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The grid-template-columns describe how many and the size of your grid columns.

To get your items in the same row, you have to change your css to something like that:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```